# Oracle APEX Cascading Select List Query

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking to perform the following using a On Demand Ajax call within Oracle APEX 4.2.

Basically, I have an two select lists where the value of the first select list is used to feed into the second select list but I have the following issue.

When I select the value from my first select list, which is then used as part of the where conditions of my second select list, the query that executes as part of the second select list may take up to a minute to return all available results. At the moment, the user switches to the second select list but is empty as the query in the backend Dynamic action is still running.

Using Ajax together with a spinner, I need a means of showing to the user that the second select list is busily processing the available results and so want to display a spinner whilst it is getting the results and then hiding the spinner when the results are all available in the second list.

I think that this would give the user a better user experience.

Comment: Don't know the answer but if it was me I'd avoid a select list for a slow query - use a popup lov instead.

Comment: Just to add to the comment from [+JeffreyKemp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp), cascading select-box page items have been around since the earlier releases of Apex from versions 4.0; take a look at my guide on [how to create LOV select popups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770135/cascading-list-of-values-with-many-to-many-relationship/22778097#22778097). The post is step-by-step list of steps to follow within Apex.

Answer (score 0):

You say you currently use a dynamic action. Have you tried using a cascading LOV? In your second select list set the page item of the first select list in the "Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)"-attribute that is under List of Values.