# Oracle APEX | How to change select list value and Submit it dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have two select lists

**1. The first one P4_country_id_B contains countries names**

```
    select country_name as d, country_id as r 
    from countries
```

**2. The second one P4_CITY_ID_B contains cities of a country based on selected value in P4_CITY_ID_B.**

```
    select city_name as d, city_id as r 
    from cities 
    where country_id = :P4_country_id_B
```

Everything goes OK without any problem.

**BUT**

I use **Execute PL/SQL Code Dynamic Action** to change selected values of those lists like this (for example):

```
:P4_country_id_B:=country_returned_value;
:P4_CITY_ID_B:=city_returned_value;
```

**Where**

```
country_returned_value : is a one value of countries list values for example (USA)
city_returned_value    : is a one value of cities list values for example (NewYourk).
```

The first selected list value changes **but** the second list never changes.

**Notes:**

- I used P4_country_id_B,P4_CITY_ID_B as **Page Items to Submit** for the dynamic action.

  - I don't whan to submit the page instead of dynamic action

**How can I change list values in this case please?.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cascading select lists are refreshed through ajax.
Change select list 1, select list 2 will be refreshed.
You execute plsql, which in turn will set the value of the items involved. Both are select lists, and one is dependent on the other.
So while both will be set, the change of the first one will cause the second to be refreshed.
In other words, you're doing it too fast. And while there is a solution, the proper way is a bit complex and I wouldn't build it in DA's personally.

You haven't specified how or when you call the code which sets the values for the items. So here I'll just assume a DA with an action of type "Execute JavaScript" (for example)

```
// perform a call to the ajax callback process to get the country and city id
// there are several ways to provide values to the process if necessary.
// for example through x01, which can be used in the proces like
//   apex_application.g_x01
apex.server.process('GET_COUNTRY_DEFAULTS', {x01:""}).done(function(data){
  // process returns JSON which contains 2 properties: country_id and city_id
  // data.country_id 
  // data.city_id

  // bind a ONE-TIME handler to the after refresh event of the city
  // cascading LOVs fire the before and after refresh events like any other
  // refreshable element in apex
  // a one time handler since the values are different each time this code will
  // execute
  apex.jQuery("#Px_CITY_ID").one("apexafterrefresh",function(){
    // after refresh of the list, attempt to set the value of the list to the
    // value retrieved earlier
    apex.item(this).setValue(data.city_id);  
  });  

  // finally, set the value of the country. Doing this will also trigger the 
  // refresh of dependent elements
  apex.item('Px_CITY_ID').setValue(data.country_id);

  // since a handler has been bound, the refresh will occur, the after refresh
  // triggers, and the value will be set properly
});
```

Finally, create a new process on the page under "AJAX Callback", and name it `GET_COUNTRY_DEFAULTS`

```
DECLARE
  l_country_id NUMBER;
  l_city_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_country_id := 8;
  l_city_id := 789;

  htp.p('{"country_id":'||l_country_id||',"city_id":'||l_city_id||'}');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  -- returning an error while using apex.server.process will prompt the user
  -- with the error and halt further processing
  htp.p('{"error":"'||sqlerrm||'"}');
END;
```

That should tie everything together.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, but it doesn't work with me, I think that is because the code have to set a value to the country_id list before every thing, because the the values of city_id list depend totally of the selected value of the country_id list.

Comment: How does it 'not work'? I can't help if you don't clarify. The reason you described is the exact reasoning I gave in my answer. My point in it is exactly that: set the country id, let the cities refresh, and then set the city id. Do you have any js problem? A simple example page on apex.oracle.com with the problem illustrated would really help to apply the solution there.

Comment: It return unexpected token in s JSON at position 0
could you see this please! :
here is an example in apex.oracle.com 

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42153:2:105276779939013:::::
Username: sadammashaal@hotmail.com
Pass: meshaal
schema: meshaal.
thank you so much.

Comment: @SaddamMeshaal I've created a copied page with all issues fixed: 1) selectors are case sensitive! `P3_DEP_LIST` instead of `P3_dep_list` 2) you use `P3_EMP_ID` in the callback process, so it has to be provided in the call, I did so through `pageItems` 3) caught possible error in callback process and return it in error json, causing the error to be shown

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. My answer below, assumes, according to your question, the first list name is `P4_country_id_B`, and the second list name is `Cities_LOV`. If that is not the case, please clarify.

Your first list called `P4_country_id_B`, and you assign it to *itself* through the following statement:

```
  :P4_country_id_B:=country_returned_value;
```

So basically, nothing has changed, the value of `P4_country_id_B` is the returned value of your list `P4_country_id_B` without any need for this assignment. Note, it is not clear to me, what is `country_returned_value`, because `P4_country_id_B` holds the returned value.

Secondly, you have a list called `Cities_LOV`, and you assign the returned value to `P4_CITY_ID_B` page item, through the following statement:

```
:P4_CITY_ID_B:=returned_city_value;
```

Again, I am not sure what is `returned_city_value`, because `Cities_LOV` holds the returned value of that list.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But I assume, you want to allow the user to select the Country first, and then based on that, you want to refresh the Cities list to display the cities in that particular country. If that is the case, then use a dynamic action on `P4_country_id_B` value change, to refresh the value of `Cities_LOV`. You only need to pass  `P4_country_id_B` to that dynamic action.

**UPDATE**

After you corrected the wording of the question, the answer would be like this:

In your child list `P4_CITY_ID_B` make sure you set the option `Cascading LOV parent item(s)` to the parent list `P4_country_id_B`. You do not need the dynamic action. The child list, should refresh upon the change of the parent list. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770135/cascading-list-of-values-with-many-to-many-relationship?), goes in details about how to implement cascading list

Comment: Sorry there was som mistakes in writing the post but now I have corrected them and clarified the confusion.